# Pandas TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Tags: python, html, pandas, dataframe, typeerror

I have a problem where two almost identical html files create different behavior on the code. If i choose the HTML file in the first picture, pandasGUI will load the dataframe just fine. However if i choose second HTML file, it throws a typeerror as stated in the title. I have tried to fix this on and off for three weeks and i am completely lost. Can anyone help? Code below.

```
import pandas as pd
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d
from pandasgui import show

pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 100)
pd.set_option('precision', 3)
file = ''

def choose_file():
    global file
    i = input("Please choose an option below: \n"
              "1: Own Team \n"
              "2: Shortlist \n")
    if (i == '1'):
        file = './own_team.html'
    elif (i == '2'):
        file = './shortlist.html'
    return file

file = choose_file()
attribute_view = pd.read_html(file)

map = interp1d([1, 7000], [1, 100])

df = attribute_view[0]

if(file == './shortlist.html'):
    for column in ['Inf', 'Name', 'Age', 'Best Pos', 'Personality', 'Acc', 'Wor', 'Vis', 'Thr', 'Tec', 'Tea', 'Tck', 'Str', 'Sta', 'TRO', 'Ref', 'Pun', 'Pos', 'Pen', 'Pas', 'Pac', '1v1', 'OtB', 'Nat', 'Mar', 'L Th', 'Lon', 'Ldr', 'Kic', 'Jum', 'Hea', 'Han', 'Fre', 'Fla', 'Fir', 'Fin', 'Ecc', 'Dri', 'Det', 'Dec', 'Cro', 'Cor', 'Cnt', 'Cmp', 'Com', 'Cmd', 'Bra', 'Bal', 'Ant', 'Agi', 'Agg', 'Aer']:
        df[column] = df[column].replace('-', 0)
    print(df)

df['Team_dna'] = (df['Agg'] + df['Ant'] + df['Det'] + df['Tea'] + df['Wor'] + df['Acc'] + df['Sta'])

# Sweeper Keeper - Attack
df['sk_at'] = map((df['Aer'] + df['Com'] + df['Fir'] + df['Han'] + df['Pas'] + df['Ref'] + df['TRO'] + df['Thr'] + df['Cmp'] + df['Dec'] + df['Vis'] + df['Acc']) * 40)
```

[image: Working HTML]

[image: Not working HTML]

**EDIT:**
Full traceback:

```
Please choose an option below: 
1: Own Team 
2: Shortlist 
2
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Pottemuld\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 149, in na_arithmetic_op
    result = expressions.evaluate(op, str_rep, left, right)
  File "C:\Users\Pottemuld\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 208, in evaluate
    return _evaluate(op, op_str, a, b)
  File "C:\Users\Pottemuld\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\computation\expressions.py", line 70, in _evaluate_standard
    return op(a, b)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Github/FM20-Analysis/FM.py", line 36, in <module>
    df['sk_at'] = map((df['Aer'] + df['Com'] + df['Fir'] + df['Han'] + df['Pas'] + df['Ref'] + df['TRO'] + df['Thr'] + df['Cmp'] + df['Dec'] + df['Vis'] + df['Acc']) * 40)
  File "C:\Users\Pottemuld\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\common.py", line 64, in new_method
    return method(self, other)
  File "C:\Users\Pottemuld\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\__init__.py", line 503, in wrapper
    result = arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op, str_rep)
  File "C:\Users\Pottemuld\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 197, in arithmetic_op
    res_values = na_arithmetic_op(lvalues, rvalues, op, str_rep)
  File "C:\Users\Pottemuld\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 151, in na_arithmetic_op
    result = masked_arith_op(left, right, op)
  File "C:\Users\Pottemuld\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops\array_ops.py", line 94, in masked_arith_op
    result[mask] = op(xrav[mask], yrav[mask])
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Comment: which line of the code throws the error?

Comment: a full traceback would be even better to help identify where the problem is

Comment: This is the line that triggers the error: 
df['sk_at'] = map((df['Aer'] + df['Com'] + df['Fir'] + df['Han'] + df['Pas'] + df['Ref'] + df['TRO'] + df['Thr'] + df['Cmp'] + df['Dec'] + df['Vis'] + df['Acc']) * 40)

Can provide full trace later today.

Comment: @AndrewPye full traceback in the post now.

Comment: This doesn't seem reproducible, but you said you've already spent days on it. I would take the line df['sk_at']... and add only one of those columns at a time inside map((...)*40) and see which column breaks it. Then try to figure out why your program thinks that column is a string.

Comment: so start with df['sk_at'] = map((df['Aer'])*40) and see if you get and error. Then df['sk_at'] = map((df['Aer'] + df['Com'])*40). see if you get the error. etc etc.

Answer (score 0):

the second image has values '-' in some columns. This will cast the entire column to a string and you won't be able to run arithmetic operations. This should do!

```
df = df.replace('-', 0)
```

Comment: Thank you, will try when i get home, but it does make sense.

Comment: I would still use that instead of looping through all of the columns